# D3.js - function don't listen for an EventListener who resize the svg

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js, addeventlistener, bind

i'm quite new with javascript and D3js and I wrap my head on somes issues,

I created a function to resize the svg and return the svg selection

```
const bodyClient = {
  width: document.body.clientWidth,
  height: document.body.clientHeight,
};

const container = d3.select("body");

function resizeSVG(container, bodyClient) {
  let svg = container.selectAll("svg").data([null]);
  svg = svg
    .enter()
    .append("svg")
    .merge(svg)
    .attr("width", `${bodyClient.width}`)
    .attr("height", `${bodyClient.height}`);
  return svg;
}
```

Attach to an EventListener on window:

```
function renderingResize() {
  return resizeSVG(container, bodyClient);
}

const svg = renderingResize();

window.addEventListener("resize", renderingResize());
```

And after a create a function who display a half PieChart and take this width and height from svg:

```
halfCircle(svg, schoolarTimeStamp, 250, 10, 180, 0, true);
```

It's like the function isn't bind to the EventListener because when I append a rect outside the function he react, and for the function only when i resfresh the page any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below a simple example of resize with D3, the svg is like a div with an overflow hidden property, so for a semi-circle you can play cx property

```js
  const svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr('style', 'background:red')
    .attr("width",window.innerWidth)
    .attr("height",window.innerHeight);
    
    svg.append('circle')
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", 90)
    .attr("r", 90)
    
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
d3.select("svg") 
.attr("width",window.innerWidth)
.attr("height", window.innerHeight);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, but for example if i center the circle in the center of the page like this : .attr("cx", window.innerWidth / 2)
 .attr("cy", window.innerHeight / 2)    and if i try to resize de window of my browser i need the resfresh the page.. can i keep tracking the center without refresh?

Comment: ```window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
d3.select("svg") 
.attr("width",window.innerWidth)
.attr("height", window.innerHeight);
d3.select("circle") 
.attr("cx", window.innerWidth/2)
.attr("cy", window.innerHeight/2)
});```